# Substitute a space to a string to force tabular cell separation

Tags: tables, macros, xstring

I'd like to construct tables using macros to align syllables with other text. For that task, I defined a table with no separation between columns. This, however led to words being stuck together if connected with an ampersand.

Substituting with `xstring` and `StrSubstitute` does not work for macros like `\hspace` or `\phantom`, and `\,` strangely produces an error. Naturally simple written spaces are ignored by the tabular environment. How could the space be inserted?

---

Here's a dummy example. First, a version with no substitutions. Then one with `\,\,`. Finally, the wanted result. For me, this example compiles with errors about inserting a missing `}` in Overleaf. But it does produce the correct result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{8}{l@{}}}
    Wo-&ah we're & half way there, && Wo-&oah & livin' on a prayer \\
    {\StrSubstitute{Wo-&ah we're & half way there, && Wo-&oah & livin' on a prayer}{& }{&\,\,}} \\
\end{tabular}

Wo-ah we're half way there, Wo-oah livin' on a prayer

\end{document}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Example]

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: Do not look at the 'output'  if you recieve an error message.

Comment: @leandriis Fair enough, but it did substitute something nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the string after the substitution and use it; you need a small `\expandafter` trickery and braces to hide the `&` from the alignment; with `\expandafter` we expand `\temp` before the group ends.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{8}{l@{}}}
Wo-&ah we're & half way there, && Wo-&oah & livin' on a prayer \\
\noexpandarg
{\StrSubstitute{Wo-&ah we're & half way there, && Wo-&oah & livin' on a prayer}
              {& }{&\,\,}[\temp]\expandafter}\temp \\
\end{tabular}

Wo-ah we're half way there, Wo-oah livin' on a prayer

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, thanks! Also, is the double `\,` a proper typing space length? I just aligned it by eye.

Comment: @Felix Since I have no idea what your aim is, so I just answered the question.